# GoogleSheet Script to Move to Sheet with same name as cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with 6 columns. Row 1 is titles and each other sheet has the same titles and columns.

[image: Sheet Sample Photo]

I have tried a couple codes like this that i found online with edits but can get it to correctly work for multiple sheets.

```
function copyrange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Source');
  var testrange = sheet.getRange('F:F');
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('target');
  var data = [];
  var j =[];

for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
  if ( testvalue[i] == 'Completed') {
  data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,25).getValues());
  //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
  j.push(i);
 }
 }


 csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);


  for (i=0;i<j.length;i++){
  var k = j[i]+1;
  sheet.deleteRow(k);


  if (!(i == j.length-1)) {
  j[i+1] = j[i+1]-i-1;
}
}
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `if ( testvalue[i] == 'Completed')` should be `if ( testvalue[i][0] == 'Completed')`  and this `var testrange = sheet.getRange('F:F');`  would be better to be this `var testrange=sheet.getRange(1,6,sheet.getLastRow(),1);`

Answer (score 1):

**Deleting Rows as you collect data that meet criteria**

```
function moveRows() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Source');
  var vA=sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var csh=ss.getSheetByName('target');
  var d=0;//deleted row counter
  var data=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    if (vA[i][5]=='Completed') {
      data.push(vA[i]);
      sheet.deleteRow(i+1-d++);//increment deleted row counter as you delete rows
    }
  }
  csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

[Sheet getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow())

[Sheet getLastColumn](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn)

Comment: this is amazing thank you I have a second question I am trying to add 9 more list options I have tried adding more variables to the code but i can seem to get it to work or have it read column 6 and move to the sheet that is listed there

Comment: What are list options?

Comment: They are just List 1, List 2 , Etc.

Comment: I still don't understand. There no mention of them in your question.  Are they columns, rows, sheets?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I appreciate the help. The value i am going going use in the final sheet instead of 'complete' is 'List 1' I have to sort my rows in up to 9 sheets all named 'List 1' 'List 2', Etc. In column F they are drop downs i will select and the row will move to the corresponding sheet. I hope that clarifies. Thanks so much